# How to get JIRA issue for branch/pull request?

Tags: jira, pull-request, jira-rest-api, bitbucket-server

I'm using both JIRA and Stash REST APIs for reading data from our systems, but I wasn't successful in finding out how to get JIRA issue(s) associated with a given pull request. I can easily get the pull request's *from* branch, so getting issue(s) associated with a given branch would work, too.

I know how to get pull request(s) associated with a given issue, that is, the other way around, but obviously I cannot scan all the issues. Also, the web interface shows the info, but I'd like to avoid using that programmatically. Surely there is a way using the API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is this REST resource to retrieve the JIRA issues for a pull request:

```
/rest/jira/1.0/projects/{projectKey}/repos/{repositorySlug}/pull-requests/{pullRequestId}/issues
```

Its response looks like:

```
[
  {
    "key": "JRA-11",
    "url": "https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-11"
  },
  {
    "key": "JRA-9",
    "url": "https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/JRA-9"
  }
]
```

It is available both for [Stash](https://developer.atlassian.com/static/rest/stash/latest/stash-jira-integration-rest.html#idp20400) and [Bitbucket](https://developer.atlassian.com/static/rest/bitbucket-server/latest/bitbucket-jira-rest.html).

Comment: Works like a charm! Thank you very much.

Comment: I have a server install of JIRA 7.2.1 and can't get this to work. Is this supported in the cloud only?

Comment: @Jason, this REST resource is available for Stash and Bitbucket, not JIRA.